# C++ : Adding rows to a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, csv, vector

I'm trying to mimic some of the dataframe functionality from R in C++, i.e., read from a CSV file into a matrix and add/remove rows. The number of rows in the CSV file can be anything, BUT the number of columns and their datatypes are fixed. So it's not supposed to be too general-purpose (i.e. variable number of columns or variable datatypes for columns). I've been able to make a basic program that reads data to a vector of string vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

using vec = vector<string>;
using matrix = vector<vec>;


matrix readCSV(string filename)
{
   char separator = ',';
   matrix result;
   string row, item;

   ifstream in(filename);
   while(getline(in, row))
   {
      vec R;
      stringstream ss(row);
      while(getline(ss, item, separator))   R.push_back( item );
      result.push_back(R);
   }
   in.close();
   return result;
}



void printMatrix(const matrix &M)
{
   for(vec row : M)
   {
      for (string s:row)    cout << setw( 12 ) << left << s << " ";
      cout << '\n';
   }
}



void deleteRow(matrix &M, int row)
{
   if(row < M.size())    M.erase( M.begin() + row );
}



void deleteCol(matrix &M, int col)
{
   for(vec &row : M)    if ( col < row.size() )     row.erase( row.begin() + col );
}



void edit( matrix &M, int i, int j, string value )
{
   if (i < M.size() && j < M[i].size())     M[i][j] = value;
}



int main()
{
   matrix pets = readCSV( "pets.csv" );
   printMatrix( pets );

   cout << "\n\n";

   deleteRow( pets, 3 );
   deleteCol( pets, 3 );
   edit( pets, 1, 2, "12" );
   printMatrix( pets );
}
```

pets.csv:

```
Animal,Name,Age,Food,Owner,Notes
Dog,Fido,6,Chewies,R. Smith,Barks
Cat,Fluffy,8,Whiskers,M. Jones,Miaows
Hamster,Giles,2,Scratchies,A. Green 
Snake,Hissie,3,Mice,Bob
```

Output:

```
Animal       Name         Age          Food         Owner        Notes        
Dog          Fido         6            Chewies      R. Smith     Barks        
Cat          Fluffy       8            Whiskers     M. Jones     Miaows       
Hamster      Giles        2            Scratchies   A. Green     
Snake        Hissie       3            Mice         Bob          


Animal       Name         Age          Owner        Notes        
Dog          Fido         12           R. Smith     Barks        
Cat          Fluffy       8            M. Jones     Miaows       
Snake        Hissie       3            Bob
```

The main issue is that all columns are of the same datatype (in this case, string). What modifications should I make to allow columns of different data types (e.g. in this case, the age columns should be int and the rest string)?
Also, how do I add new rows or columns to the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each column is a different type, that implies you should have a vector of objects, not a vector of vectors.  You're not dealing with *tabular* data, you're dealing with *records*.

Something like:

```
struct Pet
{
    std::string animal;
    std::string name;
    unsigned int age;
    std::string food;
    std::string owner;
    std::string notes;
};

// Later
std::vector<Pet> pets;
```

In this model:

> how do I add new rows to the matrix?

Push a new `Pet` object into the vector.

> how do I add new columns to the matrix?

Add a new data member to the `Pet` type.

> how can I read data from the stringstream into the struct object

Use a helper function to do the reading:

```
Pet read_pet(std::string const &row)
{
    Pet pet;

    std::istringstream ss{row};

    std::getline(ss, pet.animal, ',');
    std::getline(ss, pet.name, ',');
    ss >> pet.age;
    ss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ',');
    std::getline(ss, pet.food, ',');
    std::getline(ss, pet.owner, ',');
    std::getline(ss, pet.notes, ',');

    return pet;
}
```

> and then push that into the matrix?

```
while(getline(in, row))
{
    result.emplace_back(read_pet(row));
}
```

Comment: He seems to be writing general purpose CSV code, not something that works with predefined record types.

Comment: @Barmar It's not clear. If that's the goal then the question *"What modifications should I make to allow columns of different data types (e.g. in this case, the age columns should be int and the rest string)?"* makes absolutely no sense -- everything is a string in CSV. So either the answer is my answer, or the answer is "you don't because CSV data isn't typed."

Comment: So then "vec" is replaced by "Pet".. I'm assuming I'll no longer be able to read a line from the file into a row like before, using while(getline(ss, item, separator))   R.push_back( item );.

Comment: @u23 That is correct. You can write a helper function that will populate a `Pet` object from a line of text or an input stream, though.

Comment: @Barmar: Sorry I should've clarified (will edit question). The types of the columns are indeed predefined.

Comment: @cdhowie: You mentioned that I can push a new row to the matrix. While initially reading from the CSV, how can I read data from the stringstream into the struct object and then push that into the matrix?

Comment: @u23 Added that to my answer.

Comment: You should define extraction and insertion operators for `Pet` (e.g. `operator<<()` and `operator>>()`).

Comment: @RobK CSV is not the only possible representation for this data structure.